# How save is it to delete rows with a query in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-delete

I have an object Head (table **Head**) which can have 0 or n positions (table **Position**).

*HEAD table*

```
HEAD_ID  NAME
1        A
2        B
```

*POSITION table*

```
HEAD_ID  POS_ID  VALUE
1        1       X
1        2       Y
2        1       Z
3        1       DELETE ME
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to create foreign keys to maintain the data integrity. Therefore I want to create a delete script to delete Positions which do not have a corresponding head.

*My delete script*

```
DELETE  POSITION
WHERE HEAD_ID NOT IN (SELECT HEAD_ID FROM HEAD)
```

Question: How does the command work if rows are inserted during the execution of the delete script into the tables? In my scenario both tables have several 10.000 of rows and the search may take some time.

If I understand it correctly, the list of HEAD_IDs from HEADS is created  once at the beginning of the command. Therefore newly added rows will not be in the list and will be deleted. Is that correct?

The command would delete the position with HEAD_ID = 3 and POSITION_ID = 1 on my example, since the head is missing.

But how does it work, if after the SELECT and before the DELETE, new entries will be added to the both tables:

*HEAD table*

```
HEAD_ID  NAME
1        A
2        B
4        NEW HEAD
```

*POSITION table*

```
HEAD_ID  POS_ID  VALUE
1        1       X
1        2       Y
2        1       Z
3        1       DELETE ME
4        1       WILL I BE DELETED?
```

Will the new position with the HEAD_ID = 4 and POSITION_ID = 1 be deleted since the head was not in the SELECT?

Any way to do perform the task in a safer way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL table locking feature for you delete operation, then no new data will insert until your delete operation finish.
First Lock the tables

```
LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE
```

Then do your delete operation and after release the table lock

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

MySQL allows a client session to explicitly acquire a table lock for preventing other sessions from accessing the same table during a specific period.

A client session can acquire or release table locks only for itself. And a client session cannot acquire or release table locks for other client sessions.

Ref : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/